# modify the local Appcache in the client side using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-appcache

is it possible to modify the local app cache in the client side using JavaScript ?
i need to update the app cache each time the client view or add a new item.
**EDIT**
for example this is my appcache file :

```
 CACHE MANIFEST
 # 2014-02-13 v13.0.0

CACHE:
#HTML
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js
animation.js
test.css
```

the question is if there is a ways to update the manifest and add a new line to it in order
to add a new file to store without the intervention of the server side to be like this :

```
CACHE MANIFEST
     # 2014-02-13 v13.0.0

    CACHE:
    #HTML
    http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js
    animation.js
    test.css
    http://download.support.xerox.com/pub/docs/FlowPort2/userdocs/any-os/en/fp_dc_setup_guide.pdf
```

Comment: What sort of cache is it? Do you want to update JS/CSS/Images on the client side?

Comment: i want to update the appcache file itself in other work i want it to store new files,is there a way  to tell the appcache to add that particular file (image,js,css or any other type) in the client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do can be done, sort of. The main caveat is that each time you update your cache, it will redownload the whole lot rather than just the new files you have added.

The code to force the browser to read the new appcache file is pretty simple:

```
function updateCache(){ 
    var appCache = window.applicationCache;

    appCache.update(); 

    if (appCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
        appCache.swapCache(); 
    }
}
```

I suggest having a read of http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/ and http://appcachefacts.info/ for more information.

Comment: i am sorry that i didnt explain my problem clearly.to make it easy to understand, i have multiple client and each client , each client has his own appcache in their pc where they have their file stored. i want to know how to add a new line in the appcache file to tell it to store this new file using JavaScript without the intervention of the server.i am not talking about the update.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do this client side - you will need something server side to create the new appcache file and then you can force the clients to update accordingly.